# Using Windows Credentials for SSO in React frontend / Node backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, windows, authentication, single-sign-on

I have a react.js webapp running on an nginx server and a node.js backend running on the same nginx server, but on a different port. The app is used local in our company and I want to log the users in using SSO (we are using MS-ActiveDirectory, but not the Azure AD).

Is it somehow possible to use the windows user login data to log my users into my react/node application?